php query to get data by adding interval in date by checking value from other column
I have two tables: invoices and invoice_details.
invoice table columns are visa_status, date, visa_expiry and others.
invoice_details columns are description and others
I want to filter visa according to expiry days remaining.
For some records I have a visa_expiry record and for others records I don't have a visa_expiry record. If I don't have visa_expiry record I want to add interval according to the name of the visa.
For example if I have 60 days visa stored in invoice details I want to add 60 interval in date creation and want to get the result.
I have tried the following which is working fine for the visa_expiry column:
if($this->ci->input->post('expiry')){
    $expiry = (int)$this->ci->input->post('expiry');
    array_push($where, 'AND ' . db_prefix() . 'invoices.visa_expiry = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL '. $expiry .' DAY)');
    array_push($where, 'AND ' . db_prefix() . 'invoices.visa_status != \'exit\' AND ' . db_prefix() . 'invoices.visa_status != \'converted\'');
    
}

and I have the following query which is working fine for intervals if the visa_expiry column is empty:
if ($this->ci->input->post('expiry')) {
    $expiry = (int)$this->ci->input->post('expiry');

    $whereClause = "
    EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM (
            SELECT 
                i.rel_id,
                COALESCE(CAST(REGEXP_SUBSTR(i.description, '[0-9]+') AS UNSIGNED), 0) as interval_days
            FROM " . db_prefix() . "itemable i
            WHERE i.rel_type = 'invoice'
        ) sub
        WHERE " . db_prefix() . "invoices.id = sub.rel_id
        AND DATE_ADD(" . db_prefix() . "invoices.date, INTERVAL sub.interval_days DAY) = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL $expiry DAY)
        AND " . db_prefix() . "invoices.visa_status != 'exit' AND " . db_prefix() . "invoices.visa_status != 'converted' AND " . db_prefix() ."invoices.visa_status != 'international'
    )
    OR " . db_prefix() . "invoices.visa_expiry = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL $expiry DAY)
    ";

    array_push($where, 'AND (' . $whereClause . ')');

}

I want to merge these two queries - for example if the visa_expiry column is empty I want to get a record using interval and if visa_column has value than I want to get it according to visa_expiry only.
